# How to word my question so it won't get closed?

Tags: support

Earlier today I posted [a question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/revisions/180443/1) asking for links to examples of 45 minute presentations for the defense of an MSc in maths. This post was later closed for being a "shopping question". So I [reworded the question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/180443/111347) in a more general fashion: instead of asking for examples, I asked how to find such examples. Nevertheless, the question hasn't been opened. I'd like to post this reworded question as a new post. However, before I do so, I'd like to get tips on how to word it in such a way that it won't be closed.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see how your question could be made suitable for this site. Presentations are typically not archived in repositories and the only possibility is that someone decided to put theirs on their personal website or upload it on YouTube. Thus, I cannot see any other answer than Google and a stroke of luck.

However, when you edited your question, it was pushed in a review queue where other users can vote whether to reopen it or not. At the moment the review process for your question is still ongoing and it will finish when either (from [this faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581/300001)):

> - Three "Leave Closed" reviews
> - Post gets reopened
> - All reopen votes on the question expire
> - The question was added to the queue through an edit after being closed, and the user who edited the question later flags it as spam or
>   rude/abusive, and there are no active reopen votes from others cast
>   more than 15 minutes ago.

In any case, don't be surprised or disappointed that your advisor didn't comply with your request, many advisors don't keep their students' presentations (e.g., I don't), but they can certainly advise you on how to prepare and structure yours, and to review it at the end.